# My Blender Object is "see-through" in Unity

Tags: materials, export, transparency, unity, .fbx

I made an object. It looks good in Blender, but if I export it into Unity, it is transparent, and I can see the parts of the Object that I should not see.

For Example
In Blender:
[image]

In Unity:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see faces which face the wrong way inside Blender go to the Shading top in the top right corner of the vieport and enable Backface Culling:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJLon.png]

This is what it looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3sId.png]

Now select the faces which are facing the wrong way, press Alt N and choose either recalculate Outside or recalculate Inside depending on what you need:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNpZl.png]

Comment: This is the exact answer. thanks mate